# XDebug with Atom gets stuck

Tags: php, debian, xdebug, atom-editor

I'm trying to debug a Symfony 3 application with XDebug and Atom, I have installed the Atom plugin (php-debug) and the php-xdebug package in my Debian OS.

I added the lines

> zend_extension=xdebug.so
>
> xdebug.remote_enable=1
>
> xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
>
> xdebug.remote_connect_back=1    # Not safe for production servers
>
> xdebug.remote_port=9000
>
> xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
>
> xdebug.remote_mode=req
>
> xdebug.remote_autostart=true

to the `/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini` file and restarted the service but when I start the debugger and connect to the default host and port (127.0.0.1:9000) the debugger changes from `Listening...` to `Connected` but the page gets stuck and doesn't load without reaching any breakpoint.

Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"and connect to the default host and port (127.0.0.1:9000)"* Where/how do you "connect" to that? It's xdebug that connects to debug client (Atom in your case) not other way around...

Comment: I open it in my browser (Firefox), Am I doing it wrong? Must I open my web as usual and connect the browser plugin to that URL?

Comment: Yes -- you are doing it wrong. You do not connect to xdebug port -- it's xdebug will be connecting to your editor/IDE. With your settings xdebug should be attempting to debug every single script (so you may see approx 1 sec delay if it was unable to establish the session). Now you may need to activate debug listener in your Atom so it can accept incoming connection. I suggest just checking some Atom + Xdebug manual to see how it's done there (sorry, I'm a PhpStorm user and have never used Atom myself)

Comment: I was reading the XDebug docs but I didn't understand them very well. I will try it when I reach my computer and let you know, thank you very much

Comment: I mean -- read Atom + Xdebug not just xdebug. I, for example, do not know if you need to click/launch anything else from Atom side so it starts listening for incoming xdebug connections. In PhpStorm you either click "Debug" button and it initiates everything for you (if all configured properly, of course) .. or you can launch "Listen for Incoming debug connections" manually (the "phone handle" icon) ... which allows you to control actual debug via browser extension etc while not showing any debug tool windows until connection will be established.

Comment: If you are interested  -- see https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm . It may give you some general info so you have better understanding on how it works. But to have a better/quicker start -- just look for "Atom xdebug" on YouTube -- watching what others do should have you running in short time.

Comment: I finally got it to work, I disabled the `xdebug.remote_connect_back` because it was giving me problems and as you said, I only had to open the Symfony server url (127.0.0.1:8000) with the debugger opened. If you want to create an answer I accept it, thank you very much @LazyOne

Comment: I had to disable the `xdebug.remote_autostart` directive too because it was freezing Atom